# Inserting elements in a linked list in various indices using one function only

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, doubly-linked-list

This is the code I tried writing down to add an element in a double linked list, that takes an index and a value and adds a new element to the original list.
It is taking index and value but just adds the elements I give like a stack.

```
node *add(node *head, int index, int val)
{
node *new = create(val);
node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (head == NULL)
{
head = new;
temp = head;
//printf(":   %d",temp->data);
}
temp = head;
int i = 1;
while (i < (index - 1) && (temp->next != NULL))
{
i++;
temp = temp->next;
}
temp->next = new;
new->next = NULL;
new->prev = temp;
return head;
}
```

however this code(for a doubly linked list) just adds elements one after the other, disregarding the index passed.
My prof gave us a code for a singly linked list where he did something similar.

```
        struct Node *insert(struct Node *listp, int pos, int info) 
{
  /*Inserts a Node in list at position pos with data info
    pos>0. If pos>list length then new node added at end.
    If pos<1 adds at beginning.
  */
  struct Node *new=malloc(sizeof(struct Node)), *prev;// new is the new node we create everytime.
  //create new node and initialize fields
  new->data=info;
  new->next=NULL;
  if (listp==NULL) listp=new; 
  else
    if (pos<=1) { //negative or 1 index.
      new->next=listp; //first node bann gaya new
      listp=new; //head is pointing at new
    }
    else {
    //pos>1. Go to node at pos-1.
    prev=listp;
    int i=1;
    while ((i++<pos-1) && prev->next!=NULL) { //indexing 
      prev=prev->next;
    }
    new->next=prev->next;
    prev->next=new;
  }
  return listp;
}
```

how do I address this problem?

Comment: Fist of all: indent your code properly, for example like the samples in your learning material. As for your problem: I'd start with a pencil and a piece of paper.

Comment: There are several things you do different than in the second code you presented. Like you removed the `pos <= 1` check, you didn't use an `else` block, you call `malloc`, ...etc, ...etc. You should ask yourself "Why?".

Answer (score 0):

To implement a doubly linked list, your node needs to have pointers to the previous node and next node, then you can write something almost as similar to what your professor gave you for single linked list:-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Doubly linked list Node

typedef struct Node{
    int info;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;

} Node;


Node* insert(Node* listp, int pos, int info){
    //Allocate memory for node and its previous neighbor
    Node* new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node* prev = malloc(sizeof(Node)), *tail;
    //initialize new node with these values
    new->info = info;
    new->next = NULL;
    new->prev = NULL;

    //if head doesn't exist  then create one
    if(listp == NULL){
    

    /*
        listp gets whatever new had, ie
        listp->info = info
        listp->next = NULL
        listp->prev = NULL
    */
    Node* tail = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tail->info = 0;
    tail->next = NULL;
    tail->prev = NULL;

    listp = new;
    listp->next = tail;
    tail->prev = listp;


    }

    //Lets Loop through the List and insert node at pos
    else  {


        if(pos <= 1){
        
       
            /*
             This should replace the current head
             listp = new
            */
        
            new->next = listp;
            new->prev = listp->prev;
            listp->prev = new;
            listp = new; 
    

        }
        else{
       
            int i = 2;
            prev = listp->next;
            printf("%d\n", prev->prev->info);
            while(i != pos){
                printf("%d\n", new->info);
                prev = prev->next;
            
                i++;
            }
         
        
            new->next = prev;
        
            new->prev = prev->prev;

            prev->prev->next = new;

            prev->prev = new;


    }
}    
return listp;
}
// Test case
int main(){

    Node* listp;
    listp = insert(NULL, 0, 2);
    listp = insert(listp, 1, 3);
    listp = insert(listp, 2, 5);
    Node* cnt = listp;
    printf("|");
    while(cnt->next != NULL){
        printf("--%d-->", cnt->info);
        cnt = cnt->next;

    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that. Make any typo corrections if any

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * add_node_end - adds a new node at the end of a dllist list
 * @head: head of linked list
 * @n: integer value of node
 *
 * Return: address of new element, NULL if fails
 */

node *add_node_end(node **head, const int n)
{
    node *new, *temp;

    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    new->n = n;
    new->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        new->prev = NULL;
        *head = new;
        return (*head);
    }

    temp = *head;
    while (temp->next)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = new;
    new->prev = temp;

    return (new);
}

/**
 * add_dnodeint - adds a new node at the beginning of a dlistint_t list
 * @head: head of linked list
 * @n: integer value of node
 *
 * Return: address of new element, NULL if fails
 */

node *add_node_start(node **head, const int n)
{
    node *new;

    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    new->n = n;
    new->prev = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        new->next = NULL;
        *head = new;
        return (*head);
    }

    new->next = *head;
    (*head)->prev = new;
    *head = new;
    return (*head);
}


/**
 * node_len - returns the number of elements in a dllist list
 * @h: head of doubly linked list
 *
 * Return: number of nodes
 */

size_t node_len(const node *h)
{
    int count = 0;

    while (h)
    {
        count++;
        h = h->next;
    }
    return (count);
}



/**
 * insert_dnodeint_at_index - inserts a new node at a given position
 * @h: a pointer to a pointer of the first node of node linked list
 * @index: the position to add the new node
 * @val: the data n of the new node
 * Return: if the function fails = NULL
 *          otherwise - the address of the new node/element
 */


node *insert_dnodeint_at_index(node **h, unsigned int index, int val)
{
    node *newNode, *current;
    size_t list_length;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    if (h == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    if (index == 0)
        return (add_node_start(h, n));

    list_length = node_len(*h);


    if (index == (list_length - 1))
        return (add_node_end(h, n));

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newNode == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    newNode->val = val;
    if (*h == NULL)
    {
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        return (newNode);
    }

    current = *h;

    while (current)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            newNode->next = current;
            newNode->prev = current->prev;
            current->prev->next = newNode;
            current->prev = newNode;
            return (newNode);
        }

        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }

    free(newNode);
    return (NULL);
}
```